# How Will the Atala Plutus Integration Work?

Tags: plutus, haskell, java, atala-prism

I know that Atala prism will be used as the basis of Cardanos DiD but whenever I ask someone how it will work with Plutus, I end up hearing some new infrastructure needs to be built out.

My question is what is this infrastructure and how will it work with Plutus.